# iterating over char** without any specified bounds C++

Tags: c++

I'm currently struggling on finding a way to iterate over char** without knowing what the bounds are.

currently I have this

```
for (int i = 0; a[i] != nullptr;i++){
//do something
}
```

this issue is this will work if I have a char** that looks like this {"hey\0", "this\0", nullptr}

but I want it to work for one that looks like this {"hey\0", "this\0"} where there is no nullptr to indicate an end of input. I'm unsure if it is actually possible though, so let me know if its not.

Also I do not want to use std::string, I'm aware of the functionality and how it would be easier, but there are reasons for not using it.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: If you don't have a special value to indicate the end of the array it's not possible to determine it's size. Do you know about `std::vector`? And what reasons could there be to not use `std::string`?

Comment: yeah i'm aware of vectors and strings, just need to use char**, part of a project for uni. But in the same situation if say the char** had something like {"hey", "hello\0"}. does this mean there is no way of iterating over the first value as there is no string terminator?

Comment: Can you alter the data structur? If yes, don't design something hurts your mind. Or.. at least provide it with bound. Where does `char**` come from? Provide your context would help.

Comment: It's possible to iterate through the array of character strings without having a terminating null pointer if you know how many there are.  Is that information available?

Comment: @Hulk it is char** so doesn't that mean its pointing to an array of pointers?

Comment: @Neil ok sorry, misunderstood the snippet, in this case it is fine

Comment: @Neil One of those silly restrictions, but ok ^^ No way to do this. You wont get around appending a `nullptr` at the end of the array, or passing the length of the array along. (Or write a structure that contains pointer + length).

Comment: thanks for the comments everyone, part of the project was to adopt a defensive programming practise, so I wanted to see if there was anyway to block this from causing a seg fault if someone where to input an invalid char**. but seeing as it seems that's not possible, but to rely on a valid input, I'll just work with that.

Comment: It's even worse - segfault is the best case behavior if there is invalid input, as reading out of bounds of an array is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Actually, this is a good example to show how usefull classes can be, because they can encapsulate and enforce these kinds of invariants (that the length variable always matches the size of the array, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the size of the array, then there is no telling where it ends. This is the reason why a "sentinel value" such as the final `nullptr` is added, to mark the end of an array of unknown size.

Kind of like the regular null terminator inside a C string. Which is btw added implicitly by the `"str"` syntax; `"str"` is the same as `{'s','t','r','\0'}`. Which is why `"str\0"` doesn't make sense, because that gives you `{'s','t','r','\0','\0'}` where the final `'\0'` is waste of space.

Comment: (You could solve this by using std::array or passing the size along as a parameter.)

Comment: In terms of defensive programming, how would you go about terminating a comparison if the char array is not null terminated? is there even a way to do so?

Comment: @Neil Generally, no. Unless you can define a maximum size. But you need a guarantee that the accessed memory is valid. Consider `char a[] = {'a'};` - if you read beyond the first character, you invoke an out of bounds access, and there's no way to protect against that unless you know the size of `a`.